# Cypher 2.0 - MERGE operation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Are there any prereqs to use the ***merge*** operation? The merge examples from the Neo4j documentation such as:

```
merge (robert:Critic)
RETURN robert, labels(robert)
```

return:

An unknown error occurred, was unable to retrieve a result for you.

By the way, the "live" examples from the documentation don't work either:

```
Query:
merge (robert:Critic) 
return robert, labels(robert)
Error: invalid start of query
"merge (robert:Critic) return robert, labels(robert)"
 ^
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, that clearly is a bug. Opening a report on github.

The following works fine btw:

```
start _0 = node(0) with _0
merge (robert:Critic)
RETURN robert, labels(robert)
```

Comment: I see you found merge, too. Nice catch on the documentation/bugs.